# how to send looped javascript API data to the html webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api, dom

I have this simple code with 5 paramaters taken from an API that logs data:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
        
        console.log('For Calls')
        console.log(arr[i].league.name)
        console.log(arr[i].teams.home.name, arr[i].goals.home)
        console.log(arr[i].teams.away.name, arr[i].goals.away)
}
```

it logs this data to the console (2 sets of data shown):
[Logged Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc2Xu.png)

The issue I am having is trying to display this looped content to the website, I haven't even been able to get it on the screen so far using the .append methods.

Here is the format I am trying to create:

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="league">Data goes here</div>
    <div class="team1">Data goes here</div>
    <div class="score1">Data goes here</div>
    <div class="team2">Data goes here</div>
    <div class="score2">Data goes here</div>
</div>
```

I am aware I can give each div a class and append that way but I need this in a loop so those methods do not work for me in this circumstance.

Any Tips are Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function append() {

  let arr = [{ name: 'name1', goals: 'goals1' }, { name: 'name2', goals: 'goals2' }, { name: 'name3', goals: 'goals3' }]

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let parent = document.createElement("div")
    parent.className = 'parentDiv'

    let newElement = document.createElement("div")
    newElement.className = 'league'
    newElement.innerHTML = arr[i].name
    parent.appendChild(newElement)

    let newElement2 = document.createElement("div")
    newElement2.className = 'goals'
    newElement2.innerHTML = arr[i].goals
    parent.appendChild(newElement2)

    document.body.appendChild(parent)

  }

}
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but nothing appeared for me.

If you want you can try to do it at web console https://footballify.net/test/ or github https://github.com/Footballify/Footballify.github.io thanks

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. I edited the answer, as I forgot to add  `document.body.appendChild(parent)`. This works perfectly for me now. Just replace the array that I made with your array from your API. Let me know if you need more help